# Check if element is clickable in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm new to `Selenium` and need to check if element is clickable in `Selenium` `Java`, since `element.click()` passes both on `link` and `label`.

I tried using the following code, but it is not working:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Scenario1Test.driver, 10);

if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@id='brandSlider']/div[1]/div/div/div/img)[50]")))==null)
```

Answer (score 36):

[`elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is used for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` returns [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) if expected condition is true otherwise it will throw [`TimeoutException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html), It never returns `null`.

So if your using `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` to find an element which will **always gives you the clickable element**, so no need to check for `null` condition, you should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Scenario1Test.driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@id='brandSlider']/div[1]/div/div/div/img)[50]")));
element.click();
```

As you are saying `element.click()` passes both on `link` and `label` that's doesn't mean element is not clickable, it means returned element `clicked` but may be there is no event performs on element by click action.

**Note**:- I'm suggesting you always try first to find elements by `id`, `name`, `className` and other locator. if you faced some difficulty to find then use `cssSelector` and always give last priority to `xpath` locator because it is slower than other locator to locate an element.

Hope it helps you..:)

Comment: So should I use listeners? to check any event on the label

Comment: @SandeepKrishnappa No need, You should try to perform click first on browser console at label using javascript..and verify it receives any click event or not...if receives then definitely it will click by selenium..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur - I have a similar question. I was wondering if you could answer it for me? thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762906/selenium-is-it-okay-to-mix-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait-like-this

Answer (score 29):

There are instances when `element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()` will return `true` but still element will **not** be clickable, because it is hidden/overlapped by some other element.

In such case, `Exception` caught is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (781, 704). Other element would receive the click:
>   `<div class="footer">...</div>`

Use this code instead:

```
WebElement  element=driver.findElement(By.xpath"");  
JavascriptExecutor ex=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
ex.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

It will work.

Comment: This is exactly true, most of the people are not aware of this fact!

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Exactly , your element should be visible in UI and there should not be any overlay.

Comment: @cruisepandey visible and enable is not enough to know whether element is clickable, that's why elementToBeClickable fails in our last question we discussed, here this user explains the same in his answer.

Comment: @cruisepandey Read his answer more clearly he explains that `element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled() will return true but still element will not be clickable`

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this with another library, but I'm not sure I understand how it works. Can you explain your solution a little?

Comment: This is true and probably works in most cases but it is not the proper way of handling the problems. First - click by javascript is not the same as click by mouse - there might be some differences causing unreliable test results. Second - if the element is overlapped and not clickable - it means user cannot click it either - therefor it is correct when the test fails with an exception, as the user could not do the action either.

Answer (score 10):

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions)` won't return null, it will either meet the condition or throw `TimeoutException`.

You can check if the element is displayed and enabled

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath);
if (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()) {
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: There are instances when `element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()` will return `true` but still element will not be clickable, because Element is hidden/overlapped by some other element. In such case, Exception caught is: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (781, 704). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer">...</div>`

Answer (score 2):

There are certain things you have to take care:

- [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as [elementToBeClickable()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) once it is *located* and *clickable* i.e. **visible** and **enabled**.
- In this process, [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) will ignore instances of `NotFoundException` that are encountered by default in the `until` condition.
- Once the duration of the *wait* expires on the desired element not being *located* and *clickable*, will throw a timeout exception.
- The different approach to address this issue are:

  - To invoke `click()` as soon as the element is returned, you can use:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@id='brandSlider']/div[1]/div/div/div/img)[50]"))).click();
    ```
  - To simply validate if the element is *located* and *clickable*, wrap up the *WebDriverWait* in a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

    ```
    try {
           new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@id='brandSlider']/div[1]/div/div/div/img)[50]")));
           System.out.println("Element is clickable");
         }
    catch(TimeoutException e) {
           System.out.println("Element isn't clickable");
        }
    ```
  - If *WebDriverWait* returns the *located* and *clickable* element but the element is still not clickable, you need to invoke `executeScript()` method as follows:

    ```
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@id='brandSlider']/div[1]/div/div/div/img)[50]"))); 
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    ```

Comment: DebanjanB - I have a similar question here. Could you please answer it for me? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762906/selenium-is-it-okay-to-mix-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait-like-this

Answer (score 1):

From the source code you will be able to view that, `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()`, it will judge the element visible and enabled, so you can use `isEnabled()` together with `isDisplayed()`. Following is the source code.

```java
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element) {
        return new ExpectedCondition() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                WebElement visibleElement = (WebElement) ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element).apply(driver);

                try {
                    return visibleElement != null && visibleElement.isEnabled() ? visibleElement : null;
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException arg3) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "element to be clickable: " + element;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the class attribute contains `disabled` when the element is not clickable.

```java
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("elementId"));
if(!webElement.getAttribute("class").contains("disabled")){
    webElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> wb=driver.findElements(By.xpath(newXpath));
        for(WebElement we: wb){
            if(we.isDisplayed() && we.isEnabled())
            {
                we.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```