# How to check whether an element is clickable using Selenium - WebDriver using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application buttons are sometimes obscured by toasts. When I try to click such a button using Selenium - Webdriver I get the following error:

```
(node:11281) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Element <button class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" id="saveButton" ng-click="saveItem($event)">...</button> is not clickable at point (447, 882). Other element would receive the click: <span class="md-toast-text ng-binding" role="alert" aria-relevant="all" aria-atomic="true">...</span>
```

For Java I see that there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917788/4878398) solution to determine if a button is clickable:

```
public static boolean isClickable(WebElement el, WebDriver driver) 
    {
        try{
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What is the equivalent solution using Javascript? I see several conditions in the [documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) for the until module, but I don't see how to test if a button is clickable. Any help would be appreciated!

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912203/4878398) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912203/4878398) post describes a solution for Java. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813569/4878398) on that post a solution for Javascript is given. However I would like to wait until the element is not hidden anymore. I dont want to click the button while it is hidden, because that would invalidate my test.

P.s: I now test if a toast is visible and then wait for the toast to close before continuing my tests. However I would prefer a more general solution.

Comment: Use This : `public static void elementToBeClickable(WebDriver commonPage,
   By locator, int timeOut) {

  wait = new WebDriverWait(commonPage, timeOut);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

  LOGGER.info("Element is visible now");
  wait = new WebDriverWait(commonPage, timeOut);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));

  Actions act = new Actions(commonPage);
  act.moveToElement(commonPage.findElement(locator)).build().perform();
  LOGGER.info("Element can be clicked now");
 }`

Comment: @Kushal Thanks for your answer. This code in your answer looks like Java, while I am looking for a solution in Javascript. Do you know what the equivalent of your solution is in Javascript?

Comment: I don't know abt JS but for protractor you can try : `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable (element.all(by.id('option'))), 20000);`

Comment: @Kushal Thanks for pointing out Protractor. I was not aware yet of this test framework specially designed for AngularJS applications. I was writing my test scripts with just Selenium-Webdriver.