# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view while trying to click an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have this code:

```
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, '_eventId_confirmed')))
    print ("Page 2 is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")

btn = driver.find_element_by_name('_eventId_confirmed')

btn.click()
```

as you can see I first switch window and then check for an element, get that element (a button) and finally try to click on said button. This works maybe 2 out of 3 times but ever so often does it fail with this error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn" name="_eventId_confirmed"> could not be scrolled into view
```

When visually looking at the flow when it is executing everything seems fine (my first guess was that the window switch didn't work as expected) and the browser ends up in the expected state where I am able to manually click this button. Interestingly enough, there is no timeout or similar when this error occurs, it happens instantly during execution.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried javascript `scrollIntoView` option? `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView;",btn)` before click.

Comment: sorry missed `()`. Here is the correct code. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",btn)`

Comment: Have added the answer for it, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 3):

This problem usually arises when the element you are trying to click is present on the page but it is not fully visible and the point where selenium tries to click is not visible.
In this case, you can use javascript to click on the element, which actually operates directly on the html structure of the page.
You can use it like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("_eventId_confirmed")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 2):

As your final step is to invoke `click()` on the desired element, so instead of using the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, '_eventId_confirmed')))
```

Comment: Just a doubt, when the element is not clickable after opening the page, would the condition `element_to_be_clickable` make sense ? Because it would never be clickable if we don't scroll it into view and the condition `element_to_be_clickable` might give a timeout exception.

Comment: Well, _element_to_be_clickable()_ does scrolls by default by a certain limit. Let me know the execution status.

Comment: Can't check the OP website but i have also got ElementNotClickable exception in the past and i solved it using javascript click. Not very sure that the selenium wait for element to be clickable would scroll the element.

Comment: @SameerArora OP is using the _Python_ clients, so jumping straight away to use  javascript _click()_ would be against all best practices. You need to explore the `expected_conditions` properly. If you are _not very sure that the selenium wait for element to be clickable would scroll the element_ you need to read the documentation properly once again.

Comment: Yes, i have checked the official documentation of selenium and have checked SO as well. And there also its written that either it will return `true` or it will throw TimeoutException. References: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java and that's why i asked you for your thought process behind this.

Comment: By _documentation_ I meant the _API docs_ and the _source code_ and nothing less.

Comment: Yes, studied the code now, there is not scrolling involved in the method. The method and its subsequent methods are checking for its visibility by using `isDisplayed()`

Answer (score 1):

Here are the 2 options.

**Using selenium `location_once_scrolled_into_view` method:**

```
btn.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

**Using Javascript:**

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",btn)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228646/python-selenium-cant-sometimes-scroll-element-into-view/55228932?    noredirect=1#comment97192621_55228932"
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Contact Us']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[.='active']").location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the JS snippet but the Selenium example sounds very counterintutive?

Comment: Hmm, IntelliJ/PyCharm displays a warning `Statement seems to have no effect less... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects statements without any effect.`?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that message. I am able to run the sample script without issue. Added the script in the answer above for your reference.

Comment: I would strongly recommend the second solution. See the [source code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.location_once_scrolled_into_viewlocation_once_scrolled_into_view) for the first. For one thing, the first sentence of the comment describing the method reads: “THIS PROPERTY MAY CHANGE WITHOUT WARNING.” They don’t provide any more details than that and I’m not sure exactly what changes they are referring to but that doesn’t sound good. Second, all that function does is execute its own (more complicated) Javascript.