# Elem could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium

new to python and selenium.
For fun, I'm **scraping** a page. I have to click a first button for Comment, and then another button for All comments so I can get them all.
The first click works, but not the second.
I've set a hardcoded scroll, but still not working.

This is the python code I'm working on:

```
boton = driver.find_element_by_id('tabComments_btn')
boton.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
```

from here on, it doesnt work (it scrolls but it says 'elem cant be scrolled into view'

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1300)")
botonTodos= driver.find_element_by_class_name('thread-node-children-load-all-btn')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

botonTodos.click()
```

If I only click the first button, I'm able to scrape the first 10 comments, so this is working.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'thread-node-message')))

for elm in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".thread-node-message"):
    print(elm.text)
```

This is the part of the HTML I'm stuck in:

```
    <a href="#" class="thread-node-btn thread-node-children-load-next-btn">Load next 10 comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="thread-node-btn thread-node-children-load-all-btn">Load all comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="thread-node-btn thread-node-btn-post">Publicar un comentario</a>
```

There's a whitespace node with the tag #text between each .
Any ideas welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to retrieve your element ```botonTodos``` before the scrolling and changing the JScript to ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", botonTodos)```

Comment: Hi @Nic, thnks for answering. I wrote this `botonTodos= driver.find_element_by_class_name('thread-node-children-load-all-btn')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", botonTodos)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
botonTodos.click()` was this what you meant? Still got the same error

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(True);", botonTodos)` try that

Comment: Hi @Kajal, I'm getting a 'True is not defined' now.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different options.

```
#first create the elements ref
load_next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".thread-node-children-load-next-btn")
load_all_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".thread-node-children-load-all-btn")
# scroll to button you are interested (I am scrolling to load_all_btn
# Option 1
load_all_btn.location_once_scrolled_into_view

# Option 2
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",load_all_btn)

# Option 3
btnLoctation = load_all_btn.location
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(" + str(btnLoctation['x']) + "," + str(btnLoctation['y']) +");")
```

Test Code:
Check if this code is working.

```
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228646/python-selenium-cant-sometimes-scroll-element-into-view/55228932?    noredirect=1#comment97192621_55228932"
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Contact Us']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[.='active']").location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
```

time.sleep(1)

Comment: Hi @supputuri, with the three opts I'm still getting the cannot scroll into view :/ I'm using Mozilla, could this be an issue?

Comment: Can you please check if the test code working in Firefox. Then it's easy to figure out.

Comment: I'm getting this error: NameError: name 'time' is not defined. I have from time import sleep, but nothing else with time.

Comment: you have to `import time`.

Comment: I imported time. But it wasnt working, it didnt get any error but it just doesnt scrap all the comments. I wrote this: `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Load all comments']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
print(element.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
element.click()` and on the second line in the console I get this: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}, so it's not finding the <a>?

Comment: Can you please share the url , if it's ok.

Comment: Hi, it's a p*rn site, and I dont know the community guidelines regarding sharing that kind of content on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please `don't` share the url.

Comment: Hahaha, thank you still. WIll try to continue with all the reccomendations.