# How to handle "Other Element would receive the click:" in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have had issues finding the correct Xpath for selenium for the facebook messenger text box (the `Type a message, @name` box)...

Trying to automate a Facebook chat feature. I have tried using `by_xpath`, `by_id`, `by_name_class`, etc.. and nothing seems to work.

```
text_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_m"]/div/div[1]').click()
text_box.send_keys(msg)
```

Here is the error message:

Other Element would receive the click:

```
<div class ="_3ixn"></div>"
```

Comment: Not sure it's legal to automate the stuff on FB, check their policies. However, here the problem is not with the locator (xpath), there is some other element overlapping the element that you are trying to click.

Comment: Have you checked my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228646/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-could-not-be-scrolled-into-vie/55228932#55228932)