# How to identify a clickable element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I want to click on an `<a>` tag, which looked like an element I could click on with a selenium built-in function `click()`. I was wondering if somebody perhaps can explain how to determine if such an element is actually clickable for future selenium coding. Thanks

HTML:

```
<a class="open" data-path="/public/employees/767772/description.json" href="javascript:;" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="icon-caret-right"></span><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"> Läs mer
</font></font></a>
```

When I tried all I got was an error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56906/devtools/browser/a65af20c-af35-4f09-8390-abce557b8b87
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hugom/OneDrive/Documents/python web scraping tut/csv tutorials/freelancer.py", line 79, in <module>
    a_tag.click()
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="open" data-path="/public/employees/118883/description.json" href="javascript:;">...</a> is not clickable at point (458, 1242). Other element would receive the click: <img alt="テレビCM放映中!" src="https://cw-assets.crowdworks.jp/assets/banners/fixedfooter-20200104-2000x200-5e5bc753cfe393c01c5797c1647b4fd732631e477d4308cc653f4d994f541200.png" width="1000" height="100">
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if element is clickable in Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="open" data-path="/public/employees/118883/description.json" href="javascript:;">...</a> is not clickable at point (458, 1242). Other element would receive the click: <img alt="テレビCM放映中!" src="https://cw-assets.crowdworks.jp/assets/banners/fixedfooter-20200104-2000x200-5e5bc753cfe393c01c5797c1647b4fd732631e477d4308cc653f4d994f541200.png" width="1000" height="100">
```

...implies that the `click()` to the desired element is obstructed by another element:

```
<img alt="テレビCM放映中!" src="https://cw-assets.crowdworks.jp/assets/banners/fixedfooter-20200104-2000x200-5e5bc753cfe393c01c5797c1647b4fd732631e477d4308cc653f4d994f541200.png" width="1000" height="100">
```

The obstructing element is a banner element possibly the cookies banner and you have to dismiss the banner first.

Once you dismiss the banner to identify the clickable element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  clickable_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='open' and starts-with(@data-path, '/public/employees')]//font[.//font[contains(., 'Läs mer')]]")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I believe the OP would like to know how he could tell *in advance* whether a `click` call would succeed or not.

Comment: @DebanjanB how do I dismiss a banner?