# In Login page signing button is no clickable while automating

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[![ `<button class="main-button main-button-yellow login bg-3" tabindex="4">...</button> is not clickable at point (1101, 409).  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)`][1]][1]

Trying to login using the button Xpath but getting error message as button not clickable. But in manual it working
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7gZE.png

Comment: Try to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java

Comment: Thanks Worked with the below codehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java