# Is there any option handle popup using java with selenium which has HTML properties but hasn't any ok/accept/done button?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, popup, popupwindow

I'm automating using java selenium
I open flipkart.com in google chrome and as soon as I click on grocery it is asking for verify delivery Pincode but there is no any ok/done button to perform the task. if I open the site manually same Pincode popup is coming and I enter the Pincode then I hit on Enter button it gets open.

I've tried using action class to hit on Enter button however IllegalArgumentException occurring

Answer (score 0):

I have checked mentioned place and it seems that 'Submit' button is activated after a moment after typed code and some validation in background. You might need to add some wait for button to be clickable like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java).

Then you can try clicking with xpath like:

```
//div[text() = 'Submit']
```

(As there are no many characteristic attributes around).

As for 'IllegalArgumentException' your code sample might be necessary.

Comment: I've checked with above given xpath and checked putting some waits but didn't work