# How to interact with element while webpage is still loading - java selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to wait 20 seconds until the webpage spinning circle stops, then i can interact with my elements

[webpage loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYXwm.png)

i set up explicit wait so it waits for webpage to load then it can proceed. But the website itself takes 15-20 seconds until spinning circle stops.

Manually i can click into anything right away
Is there a way to interact with elements while webpage is still loading

i manually click same tab multiple times and it still takes time to load, not a cache related issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if element is clickable in Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327049/check-if-element-is-clickable-in-selenium-java)

Comment: you might try setting a pageloadstrategy of eager or none: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy

Answer (score 0):

Genrally, Page load waits often wait for the DOM to load completely before allowing the WebDriver to continue. For instance, WebDriver will only run the next line of the script when the page has fully loaded if an automated test clicks on the "Add to Cart" button on a website. It is not necessary to give WebDriver separate instructions to wait for page load in these situations.

So, ideally you should wait until the DOM is loaded successfully.

Note: If your application is taking more around 5-20 secs to load, then discussion with developers and getting the performance improved can be a better solution